# Set "flat rate" shipping method as default in woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart

I have a woocommerce website and I have set 2 shipping methods:

- Flat Rate
- Local pickup

I would like to set the "Flat rate" shipping method as default (selected) in the cart or checkout page.

Comment: where is your code,what have you tried?

Comment: i think you need to change selection/priority https://help.extensionworks.com/hc/en-us/articles/206964358-Using-the-default-WooCommerce-shipping-option-and-how-to-configure-this-

Comment: You should give shopper option to choose, don't force it.

Comment: Point A works for me @LoicTheAztec

Comment: @ChandanSahu Ok I have removed the other unnecessary code. thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) You can use the following code (to set "flat rate" shipping method as default) In cart page:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_cart', 'set_default_chosen_shipping_method', 5 );
function set_default_chosen_shipping_method(){
    //
    if( count( WC()->session->get('shipping_for_package_0')['rates'] ) > 0 ){
        foreach( WC()->session->get('shipping_for_package_0')['rates'] as $rate_id =>$rate)
            if($rate->method_id == 'flat_rate'){
                $default_rate_id = array( $rate_id );
                break;
            }

        WC()->session->set('chosen_shipping_methods', $default_rate_id );
    }
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (active theme or in any plugin file).*

Tested and Works in WooCommerce 3+

---

2) You can also reorder the shipping rates in your shipping zones settings *(but it doesn't really works as the last chosen shipping method take the hand)*.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following code to set 'any' shipping method as default.

```
function reset_default_shipping_method( $method, $available_methods ) {
    $default_method = 'wf_fedex_woocommerce_shipping:FEDEX_GROUND'; //provide the service name here
    if( array_key_exists($method, $available_methods ) )
        return $default_method;
    else
        return $method;
}
```

Let's say, you're using a Carrier shipping plugin like [WooCommerce FedEx Shipping Plugin](https://www.pluginhive.com/product/woocommerce-fedex-shipping-plugin-with-print-label/). You can fetch the value Id (shown below) and paste it under the '$default_method' in the above code.

You will have to copy and paste the code in **WordPress Dashboard->Appearance–>Editor–>functions.php** of your theme.

Hope that helped. :)

[copy the value Id from here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4HAdn.png)